# Rigorous definition of extended real line in defining measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I read the definition of [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)). Everything looks fine except the concept of extended real line. Is there a clear definition of $\infty$ and how to understand arithmetic on $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about $[0, \infty]$ is that we're *formally* adding a maximum to the interval $[0, \infty)$. So this "$\infty$" is really just a symbol that we've declared has the property that $x \leq \infty$ for every $x \in [0, \infty]$.

For arithmetic, we really only need to define what "$x + \infty$" is in order to make sense of the definition of a measure, with addition appearing in the $\sigma$-additivity and multiplication not appearing within the definition. Perhaps intuitively, we set $x + \infty = \infty + x = \infty$ for all $x \in [0, \infty]$.

Multiplication does arise in other scenarios, for example in defining product measures. In these cases it is typical to define $x \cdot \infty = \infty \cdot x = \infty$ for $x > 0$ and $0 \cdot \infty = \infty \cdot 0 = 0$. For example, if we're considering the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the measure of $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ should be equal to $0$, corresponding to $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$. Another way multiplication might appear is in calculating the Lebesgue measure $\lambda(c E)$ where $c > 0$ and $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set. We'd like to say that the measure should be equal to $c \lambda(E)$, but this requires that $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ since $0 \cdot E$ is either $\emptyset$ (if $E = \emptyset$) or $\{0\}$ (otherwise), both of which have Lebesgue measure zero. More generally, in $n$-dimensional space if $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, then $\mathbf{A} E = \{\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{x} \in E\}$ has measure $\lambda(\mathbf{A} E) = |\det(\mathbf{A})| \cdot \lambda(E)$; if $|\det(\mathbf{A})| = 0$ then the image $\mathbf{A} E$ is contained in a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension at most $n-1$, hence has zero $n$-dimensional content.

It should perhaps be mentioned that in measure-theoretic probability theory, all of these issues disappear since the measures will fall within $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Is there a set-theoretic definition of $\infty$?

Comment: You can let $\infty$ be any set which does not belong to $\mathbb{R}$. A "natural" choice you could  make is related to the Dedekind cut construction of $\mathbb{R}$, in which $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as the set of all pairs $(A, B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that (1) $A \cap B = \emptyset$, (2) $A \cup B = \mathbb{Q}$, (3) $A$ has no maximum element, and (4) every element of $A$ is $\leq$ every element of $B$. To turn this into a construction of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$, drop the "nonempty" hypothesis...

Comment: ...  and define $\infty = (\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset)$ and $-\infty = (\emptyset, \mathbb{Q})$. The natural ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ under this construction says $(A, B) \leq (C, D)$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$, so we indeed have $(\emptyset, \mathbb{Q}) \leq (A, B) \leq (\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset)$. This works well with $+$ too: adding $(A, B)$ and $(C, D)$ is defined so that the first component of the resulting Dedekind cut is given by $\{p + q \mid p \in A, q \in C\}$ (and the first component uniquely determines the second), so...

Comment: ... $(\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset) + (A, B)$ has first component equal to $\mathbb{Q}$ so long as $A \neq \emptyset$. In particular, we get $\infty + x = \infty$ for all $x \geq 0$. This works out for multiplication too, though the definition of multiplication of Dedekind cuts is more complicated than addition. Suffice to say, if $(A, B)$ is a positive Dedekind cut (so $A$ contains a positive rational) then $(\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset) \cdot (A, B) = (\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset)$. All that having been said, what "matters" is how $\infty$ interacts, not what set it *specifically* is.

Answer (score 1):

In measure theory (for positive real measures) your measure can take value $+\infty$ (never $-\infty$) and you define $\infty+\infty=\infty$, $a\times\infty=\infty$ for $a>0$ and, importantly, $0\times\infty=0$. There are different ways to extend the real line, but this is the most convenient for measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

The **extended real number system** is $\widehat{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{ -\infty, \infty \}$ with the rules

\begin{align}
-\infty \leq &x \leq \infty, x \in \widehat{\mathbb R}\\
-\infty < &x < \infty, x \in \mathbb R\\
x \pm \infty &= \pm \infty, x \in \mathbb R\\
\infty + \infty &= \infty\\
- \infty - \infty &= -\infty\\
x \cdot (\pm \infty) &= \pm \infty, x > 0\\
x \cdot (\pm \infty) &= \mp \infty, x < 0\\
0 \cdot (\pm \infty) &= 0.
\end{align}

The **big no-no** is $\infty - \infty$, because that, combined with the rules above, quickly leads to absurdity.

As an addendum, if you consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$, then the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\widehat{\mathbb R}$ requires some adjustment, because you need a different topology on $\widehat{\mathbb R}$.